# How do i get HTTP status code 200 instead of 202 from an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

The below code always receives a HTTP '202 Accepted' status code:
[image]

When I try the same API using postman I get 200 OK":
[image]

```js
function ExportStatus() {
  function ExportStatusAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/" + groupId + "/reports/" + reportId + "/exports/" + exportId + "",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 200) {
          GetExportFile()
        } else {
          ExportStatusAjax()
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(error)
      }
    });
  }

  ExportStatusAjax()
}
```

Comment: What is the difference for you?  You can use this as well  if(jqXHR.status==200 || jqXHR.status==202 ){}

Comment: There is a status parameter in the response .The Http 202 status code gives me status:"Running" , Where as Http 200 status code gives status:"Succeded".The GetExportFile() function only runs if its status:"Succeded".

Comment: I think  GetExportFile() can run when you want to run it. Doesn't matter what is the code

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention this, the GetExportFile() is another Ajax call which only runs after the status is succeded. If i run the GetExportFile() with HTTP status code 202 it throws an error "Export is still running".

Comment: Ok, but the point is that you just need to update ***your*** code so that the `if` condition looks for `200` or `202` responses - as outlined in @Serge's first comment. Alternatively, find out what differences there are in the request you make between the 2 sources and fix that problem.

Comment: I tried running it when as said by @Serge's first comment.it throws an error "Export is still running".

Comment: I think the implication is that a `202` indicates asynchronous processing and therefore, the file is not available yet.

Comment: @Brandon yes that is whats happening, I also tried giving it a timeout and then running the ExportStatusAjax() hoping it would have finished the request and return HTTP "status code 200" but it still returns 202.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Power BI, so I can't say for sure, but judging by your code and the API status codes, this looks like a case of an asynchronous API. What that means is, instead of the traditional model in HTTP where the client submits a request and gets the response back (this is a 200, a.k.a. `OK`), a client submits an HTTP request and the response is a placeholder to tell you that the real response is not ready yet.

`202` is called `Accepted` and I believe that in this situation it is being used to indicate your request has been accepted into a queue. The idea being that, if you keep retrying, eventually it will be done and you'll get the real response, which comes with a status code of `200`. Reports, analytics, or other sorts of computationally expensive workloads often follow this pattern.

This approach is a common pattern. If that is in fact what is happening here, then your code is probably correct and seeing the response flip between `202` and `200` is normal.

With that said, your approach is constantly hammering the server. As soon as it gets back a `202`, it immediately retries, which adds load to the remote system, which theoretically may actually slow it down.

I suggest putting in a timer to delay the retries, maybe every 3 seconds or 5 seconds or so. The `setTimeout` function can help you.

Comment: I added a delay like you suggested and I receive 200 eventually. But it takes around 100 to 150 seconds where as in postman it takes about 2-3 seconds. Any idea why it takes that long here?

Comment: Are you testing with Postman after and using the exact same URL?

Comment: Yes, im using the exact Same URL, in postman it doesnt return 202. it returns 200 in first attempt itself  within 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Likely because loading it via your web page resulted in the backend processing being done. If it's a queue, once the task is done, it's done. It would remain a 200.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursion that will never end. ExportStatusAjax() calls itself in 2 places at least. Remove it from your code at all. And don' t pay to much attention to the status codes if  there are  not 400x or 500x. As soon as it returns to success you are ready to continue.

Comment: I'm calling ExportStatusAjax() again because im not receiving Status code 200. Also i understand 202 is a success. But , Unfortunately i cant continue as i receive" Export operation is still in process" if i move on with status code 202.

Comment: @attacker88 If you call  it again you will never receive 200.  As soon as code return to sucess you can continue. Nobody ever checks any code on success in ajax

Comment: `And don' t pay to much attention to the status codes if there are not 400x or 500x. As soon as it returns to success you are ready to continue.` Status codes are not random. Specific codes are returned for specific reasons.